# Continus assignment to verilog module instance

Tags: verilog, assign, dataflow

Is it possible to use `assign` keyword  with module instances?

Lets assume I have a module `logarithm` which works as it's intended. In some other module, I want to have: `A = log(B) + log(C)`.

Is there any efficient way other than the following to do so?

```
wire [3:0] logB;
wire [3:0] logC;

Logarithm log(logB, B);
Logarithm log(logC, C);

assign A = logB + logC;
```

And is it known as a gate-level design or a data-flow one?
If it is not data-flow, would you please present a data-flow alternative to this code?

Comment: you need to start reading about verilog basics. it is very different from regular programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Well your `assign` keyword in the code is not working on module instances. Rather, it is working on the **outputs** of those module instances.

The way you are assigning to `A` should help you get the desired output provided you have set its width accordingly. And it is a data flow representation

There is one mistake in your given lines of code though. You can not use the same instance name `log` for both the instantiations of the module `Logarithm`. They have to be unique.